# ASP.NET MVC 5 - Passing user chosen stylesheet to _Layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created a Settings page where the user can select a Bootswatch theme from a dropdown list. The CSS theme files are located in `~/Content/themes`. The corresponding SettingsController stores the name of this theme choice in the database. **How can I load the value into the _Layout view using** `@Scripts.Render("~/Content/themes" + themeName)`? So that the theme is loaded on every page.

I am struggling with the fact that _Layout.cshtml doesn't have a controller and how I should fetch the data from the db, i.e. using a model or controller, or something completely else.

Here is a simplified structure overview:

```
Website
    Areas
        User
            Controllers
                >SettingsController.cs //here I store the value in the db
            Views
                Settings
                    >Index.cshtml //settings page view
            >_ViewStart.cshtml
    Controllers
    Views
        Shared
            >_Layout.cshtml
        >_ViewStart.cshtml
```

Comment: Do you have different `Layout.cshtml` for different dropdown options?

Comment: @ramiramilu no, should I?

Answer (score 0):

you can Read current Selected Layout from database and according to select your Layout . you can idea like this :

```
switch (SystemInfo.Theme)
        {
            case 1:
                Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Layouts/Themes/Blue/_LayoutMain.cshtml";
                break;
            case 2:
                Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Layouts/Themes/nice/_LayoutMain.cshtml";
                break;
           default:

            Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Layouts/Themes/default/_LayoutMain.cshtml";
            }
```

you can put this code in your `_viewstart` and don't set `Layout` for Views.